# error in my code when delete file?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I edit pic file in path and create new image file for there.my code is:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(string.Concat(Server.MapPath("/"), "tmp/"));
foreach (string path in files)
{
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(path);
    using (Bitmap b = new Bitmap(string.Concat(Server.MapPath("/"), "tmp/", filename)))
    {

        SolidBrush pixelBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b);
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, 105, 40);

        string outputFileName = string.Concat(Server.MapPath("/"), "tmp\\E", filename);
        MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream();
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        b.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        byte[] bytes = memory.ToArray();
        fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        fs.Close();
        memory.Close();
        b.Dispose();
    }
    File.Delete(path);
}
```

when delete old file error happend is:

> Additional information: The process cannot access the file
>   'G:\project\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\tmp\b381ae6.jpg' because
>   it is being used by another process.

how to fix it?

Comment: I use Using(...) , error  happened

Comment: @GuruprasadRao The OP used using, so the file stream is supposed to close automatically as in the answer said, so I don't think that post helps much..

Comment: Give the folder(where the files are in) access to everyone (in sharing)..
and try to list filename you will delete and delete them outside foreach loop

Comment: Try keeping all the stuffs in one `using` and check you are still getting error?

Comment: ok.i edit code.error happened.

Comment: its work.i sure not open files in elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping Graphics with *using* will fix it. You should dispose it also.

```
            using (Bitmap b = new Bitmap(filePath))
            {
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
                {
                    ...
                }
            }
```

Also you can use using statements by combining them.

```
        foreach (var path in files)
        {
            var filename = Path.GetFileName(path);
            var filePath = string.Concat(tmpPath, filename);
            using (var b = new Bitmap(filePath))
            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
            {
                g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, 105, 40);
                var outputFileName = string.Concat(newPath, filename);

                using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
                using (var fs = new FileStream(outputFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                {
                    b.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    var bytes = memory.ToArray();
                    fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }
            }
            File.Delete(path);
        }
```

Comment: Won't `b` be disposed at the end of the outer `using`? What's the advantage of calling `Dispose` directly?

Comment: its true.i forget to  Dispose it.thanks.

Comment: @mdm, I don't prefer using Dispose myself, instead use using statement. What I m sayin is the Graphics object should be disposed so wrapping it with using statement will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

write code in using scope and  check File exists

## Example

```
 using (var b = new Bitmap(filePath))
            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(b))

  using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
                using (var fs = new FileStream(outputFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))

bool exists = File.Exists("Path");

if(exists)
{
  // Code Here 
}
```

Comment: Files is Exists but used by another process.

Answer (score -1):

You need to close the filestream before doing other operations on that file ;)

Comment: the OP used "using" already, so the filstream supposed to close automatically;

Comment: i close it.but  error .....

Comment: i think error is on Directory.GetFiles()!?

Comment: then maybe the problem occurs because he is doing the delete inside the foreach instruction